# Aggregate and sum json data in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am new to python, using python3. I have json data like:

```
{
    "message": {
        "count": 46,
        "limit": 1000,
        "schools": [
            {
                "class": "1",
                "class_id": "1c8***",
                "charges": [
                    {
                        "cost": 10,
                        "breakdown": [
                            {
                                "books": "1",
                                "unitQuantity": "10"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "area": "maccau"
            },
            {
                "class": "2",
                "class_id": "1c3***",
                "charges": [
                    {
                        "cost": 100,
                        "breakdown": [
                            {
                                "books": "1",
                                "unitQuantity": "100"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "area": "maccau"
            },
            {
                "class": "1",
                "class_id": "1c3***",
                "charges": [
                    {
                        "cost": 10,
                        "breakdown": [
                            {
                                "books": "1",
                                "unitQuantity": "10"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "area": "maccau"
            },
            {
                "class": "2",
                "class_id": "1c8***",
                "charges": [
                    {
                        "cost": 50,
                        "breakdown": [
                            {
                                "books": "1",
                                "unitQuantity": "50"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "area": "maccau"
            }
        ],
        "url": {
            "link": "/"
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to use json.loads to load data and I am trying to get results like:

```
class   Cost
1       20
2       150
```

I tried converting json to a dictionary:

```
item_dict = json.load(json_data)
```

Tried to get data out using for loop and checking if class = 1 and then summing up the cost. But I feel like that is not the best approach. Can someone please tell me what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: yes, you can use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`

Comment: @Yuca - Is there any other way without using third-party library?

Comment: there's not an easier nor better documented one as far as I know. You can even use pandas to load the JSON

Comment: @Yuca - ok thank you! Will try that.

Comment: @Yuca - Unable to convert this to pandas? I converted it but it comes all under one column call message. How can I aggregate based on that?